# Right-to-left text seems to be displaying out of order

Tags: internationalization, right-to-left

I have the following text:

> $3.00 x 2 = $6.00

When I apply `direction: rtl;` to the body of the page, this text displays as

> x 2 = $6.00 $3.00

Can anyone explain why it's displaying this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A full answer to your question would have to explain how the [Unicode Bidirectional Algorithm](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr9/) works, and it's immensely complicated.

From my limited understanding, the algorithm has detected that "x 2 = $6.00" and "$3.00" are two separate "runs" of text that should be displayed in left-to-right order. As the whole block is right-to-left, you see the two runs in RTL order.

It's not clear if your question is trying to solve a problem, or if you're just curious. However, if you need to display your equation fully LTR, but in the middle of some other RTL text you can use [Unicode control characters](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-bidi-unicode-controls).

e.g. The text in this RTL block will display the text between the [two markers](https://apps.timwhitlock.info/unicode/inspect/hex/202a/202c) as a continuous run of LTR text.

```
<body dir="RTL">
    &#x202A;$3.00 x 2 = $6.00&#x202C;
</body>
```

Simpler in most cases (if you can) is to isolate the LTR text with HTML elements, e.g:

```
<body dir="RTL">
    <span dir="LTR">$3.00 x 2 = $6.00</span>
</body>
```

As I can't read Arabic or Hebrew I can't tell you how your example text should appear when embedded into RTL script. However, you do have control over the rendering.